# D3 Element on click not updating React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

Im using D3 with react `useEffect` hook and i have click method wrapped with `useCallback` hook and its updating the state, but when I'm clicking the element state is not updating at all. To stop re-rendering the D3 SVG element I don't want to add `counter` as dependency to `useEffect` hook.

Is their way I can update the `counter` state without adding `counter` on `useEffect` dependency?

[CodeSandbbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-hodgkin-d953wt?file=/src/App.js:0-638)

```
import { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";

export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
      console.log(counter);
  }, [counter]); 

  useEffect(() => {
    const svg = d3.select("#svg");

    //naming the selection
    const redRect = svg
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("width", 300)
      .attr("height", 300)
      .attr("fill", "red")
      .attr("id", "red-rect");

    redRect.on("click", handleClick);
  }, []); // should not re-render the d3 with counter as the dependency 

  return <svg id="svg" />;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way to block useEffect redo all the D3 things with `useRef`, I use the useRef value as `D3 SVG rect` then I'm checking if `rectRef.current` exists then ignore the D3 methods and bind the `handleClick` to `rectRef.current` its working.

```
import { useEffect, useState, useCallback, useRef } from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";

let calls = 0;

console.log();

export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const rectRef = useRef(null);

  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
  }, [counter]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (rectRef.current === null) {
      const svg = d3.select("#svg");
      calls += 1;
      console.log("Re-rendered: " + calls); // calls only one time
      //naming the selection
      rectRef.current = svg.append("rect");
      rectRef.current
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width", 300)
        .attr("height", 300)
        .attr("fill", "red")
        .attr("id", "red-rect");
    } else {
      rectRef.current.on("click", handleClick);
    }
  }, [handleClick]);

  return (
    <div>
      <svg id="svg" />

      <div>{counter}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-hodgkin-d953wt?file=/src/App.js:0-917)

Answer (score 1):

Pass a function to `setCounter`. The parameter of that function is the previous value of the state.

```
const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    setCounter((prev) => prev + 1);
  }, []);
```

---

`useCallback` is not necessary here though, since `setCounter` does not change identity. `useReducer` is a better hook for just incrementing as well.

```
  const [counter, incrementCounter] = useReducer((x) => x+1, 0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("render"); // Renders once (or twice in strict mode)
    const svg = d3.select("#svg");

    //naming the selection
    const redRect = svg
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("width", 300)
      .attr("height", 300)
      .attr("fill", "red")
      .attr("id", "red-rect");

    redRect.on("click", incrementCounter);
  }, [incrementCounter]); // dependency is not necessary, but doesn't hurt.
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-shadow-zzdr2u?file=/src/App.js)

---

Snippet

```js
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(<App />);

let calls = 0;

function App() {
  const [counter, incrementCounter] = React.useReducer((x) => x + 1, 0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    calls += 1;
    console.log("Re-rendered: " + calls); // Renders once (or twice in strict mode)
    const svg = d3.select("#svg");

    //naming the selection
    const redRect = svg
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("width", 300)
      .attr("height", 100)
      .attr("fill", "red")
      .attr("id", "red-rect");

    redRect.on("click", incrementCounter);
  }, [incrementCounter]); // dependency is not necessary, but doesn't hurt.

  return (
    <div>
      <svg id="svg" />
      <div>{counter}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
svg {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```